# Adding together two amounts from different sheets on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet, which has two sheets within.

I want to take an £ amount from Sheet 1, and a £ amount from Sheet 2, and add them together in Sheet 3.

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].